# Kubernetes ingress with backend serviceName regex/wildcard or selector

Tags: kubernetes, apache-flink, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-service, blue-green-deployment

Hi all we have a Flink application with blue-green deployment which we get using the Flink operator.

[Flinkk8soperator](https://github.com/lyft/flinkk8soperator) for Apache Flink. The operator spins up the following three K8s services after a deployment:

```
my-flinkapp-14hdhsr (Top level service)
my-flinkapp-green
my-flinkapp-blue
```

The idea is that one of the two among blue green would be active and would have pods (either blue or green).

And a selector to the the active one would be stored in the top level `myflinkapp-14hdhsr` service with the selector `flink-application-version=blue`. Or green. As follows:

```
Labels:  flink-app=my-flinkapp
         flink-app-hash=14hdhsr
         flink-application-version=blue
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          flink-app=my-flinkapp,flink-application-version=blue,flink-deployment-type=jobmanager,
```

I have an ingress defined as follows which I want to use to point to the top level service.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
      sub_filter '<head>' '<head> <base href="/happy-flink-ui/">';
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url: "https://$host/oauth2/auth"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-signin: "https://$host/oauth2/start?rd=$escaped_request_uri"
  name: flink-secure-ingress-my-flink-app
  namespace: happy-flink-flink
spec:
  rules:
    - host: flinkui-myapp.foo.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /happy-flink-ui(/|$)(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: my-flinkapp-14hdhsr // This works but....
              servicePort: 8081
```

The issue I am facing is that the top level service keeps changing the hash at the end as the flink operator changes it at every deployment.. eg. myflinkapp-89hddew  .etc.

So I cannot have a static service name in the ingress definition.

So I am wondering if an ingress can choose a service based on a selector or a regular expression of the service name which can account for the top level app service name plus the hash at the end.

The `flink-app-hash` (i.e the hash part of the service name - 14hdsr) is also part of the Labels in the top level service. Anyway I could leverage that?

Wondering if default backend could be applied here?

Have folks using Flink operator solved this a different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately that's not possible OOB to use any kind of `regex/wildcards/jsonpath/variables/references` inside `.backend.serviceName` inside Ingres controller.
You are able to use regex only in `path`: [Ingress Path Matching](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/ingress-path-matching/)

And its not going to be implemented soon: [Allow variable references in backend spec](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/7739) is in the hanged stage.

Would be very interesting to hear any possible solution for this. It was previously discussed on stack, however without any progress: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60810435/9929015